# resizableImageWithCapInsets won't strech Image for UITableViewCell Background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm customising the background of a `UITableViewCell`. I use the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  }
    UIImageView* uiv= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bkgCell44.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)]];
uiv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
cell.backgroundView = uiv;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return cell;

}
```

The image is displayed, but it's not streched at all...

Any help to point at what I'm doing wrong ?
Same code used to work fine for buttons and Nav bars...

Comment: Have you tried `uiv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;`?

Comment: cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bkgCell44.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)]]; try like this.

Comment: that's what I tried originally, but the image wouldn't resize...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   UIImageView* uiv= [[UIImageView alloc]init];
   uiv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bkgCell44.png"];
   uiv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
   uiv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   cell.backgroundView = uiv;
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did, it gives poor look-and-feel result, because the image isn't tiled (streching in that case results into horizontal lines)

Comment: use uiv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;